# Can I play on my Xbox one with someone else that is on a Xbox 360?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-one, xbox-network, backwards-compatibility

Am I able to play my Xbox one online and join my friends game who is playing on a Xbox 360? If so what games?

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered:

"This depends on two main factors:I am running an Xbox One version of the game on my Xbox One, in almost every game the multiplayer functionality does not support cross-platform features.
There are very few exceptions, such as World of Tanks allowing for cross-platform gaming.I am running an Xbox 360 version of the game on my Xbox OneYes.
This is through the backward compatibility feature. More details can be found from the official site here:> [Xbox One Compatibility fetaure](http://www.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/backward-compatibility) Here is a relevant question from the FAQ section:Can I do multiplayer gaming with friends who are playing the game on Xbox 360 or Xbox One?Yes. 
For games that offer multiplayer gaming, you'll be able to play with others who own the title on Xbox 360.The list of supported games can be found on the official site here:

> [Supported Games](http://www.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/backward-compatibility/available-games)